# Circuitikz - extend arrow length

Tags: circuitikz

In this circuit, made using `CircuiTikZ`,

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}  
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}  

\begin{circuitikz}

\draw
(0,6) to [short,*-] (1,6)
(0,0) to [short,*-] (1,0)
(0,6) node [left] {$A$}
(0,0) node [left] {$B$}
(0,0) to [european voltages,open,v^=$v$]    (0,6)
;

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

the arrow indicating the voltage between A and B is too short, due to the distance of the two extreme points. Is there a way to extend the length of the arrow, so that its ends could be nearer to A and B?

Answer (score 4):

You can change it with `voltage/distance from node=` key. I have also added `voltage/bump b=20pt,voltage/european label distance=20pt,` just in case you want to change them too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ctikzset{voltage/bump b=20pt,voltage/european label distance=20pt,voltage/distance from node=.1}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}

\draw
(0,6) to [short,*-] (1,6)
(0,0) to [short,*-] (1,0)
(0,6) node [left] {$A$}
(0,0) node [left] {$B$}
(0,0) to [european voltages,open,v^=$v$]    (0,6)
;

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]